# Azure Blob - getting list of blobs without knowing container name

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I have a requirement where I need to fetch blob files within subdirectory of a blob container.
Problem is I will not know the container name as containers are dynamically created.

I do not want to fetch list of containers, iterate through them and then get list of blobs. Just trying to avoid loops since there could be many containers.
Is there any simple way of getting all blobs from all containers without knowing container name?

Regards,

Madhu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer to your question is that it's not possible to get a list of blobs without knowing the container name as blobs belong to a container. You would need to know the name of the blob container to list the blobs in that container.